# How can I set a random timestamp for a row based on a columns value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query

I have an app that I built and found an issue with it.

Essentially there are created_at and ended_at timestamp columns.

The ended_at function in my app had a bug so now I have a few hundred thousand rows that have no ended at timestamp.

I want to go through each row and based on the created_at column, generate an ended_at timestamp that's anywhere from 5 seconds to 8 hours away.

This is what I came up with, I just want to make sure it's what I want before I run it on 500k rows.

```sql
UPDATE streams SET ended_at = FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 28800))
    )
    WHERE ended_at IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

I have tested it and it appears to function correctly and i have backups of my database, but I just want to be 100% sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to check out a computed column as part of a read only select first just to make sure it shows the values I'd expect.

```
SELECT *
    ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 28800)) as ended_at_new
        from streams
            WHERE ended_at IS NULL
```

If you see the correct variation and values you were expecting to see then your update query will work fine.

For extra protection you could run the update in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html):

```
begin tran;

UPDATE streams SET ended_at = FROM_UNIXTIME(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 28800))
    )
    WHERE ended_at IS NULL

select count(ended_at) where ended_at IS NULL #should see 0

select * from streams limit 0, 1000; #add better filters to correctly identify records you want to check

rollback tran;
```

If you are happy with what you saw, change the `rollback` to `commit` and run it again.

Comment: Bug:  This fails to provide a minimum of 5 seconds.

Comment: @RickJames What do you mean? Theres no chance I'll get a result thats only 5 secs further?

Comment: @ahackney - OP said "anywhere from 5 seconds to 8 hours away".

Comment: So then what should the formula be?